# How to pass a reference when initializing a servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

How would I go about passing a reference to the initialization of a servlet?

So, let's say I have something like this in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestTestServlet V3.1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xxx.servlet.RestTestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serviceConsumerKey</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xxx.oauth.ConsumerKey</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

When I try to get the parameter, of course I just get the literal string value ("com.xxx... etc).

The com.xxx.oauth.ConsumerKey is a string bean I pull from JNDI, but I'm not sure how to get the servlet to be aware of it. I'm using Spring.

Is there a way to do this via the web.xml? If not, how would you go about doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "...get the servlet to be aware of it." meaning?

Comment: I want the servlet to be able to have the value of the com.xxx.oauth.ConsumerKey bean. So, I pass it that bean, and then there'd be some way to get the string value of that bean.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. What is a "string bean"? What "to be aware of it" mean? What's wrong with getting the value from the `ServletConfig`?

Comment: How would I set a bean on the servlet via an init-param (or other method)? So I have a java.lang.String bean called com.xxx.oauth.ConsumerKey and I want the servlet to be have access to that bean. I can't just pass in the value itself. Essentially, I want constructor like behavior where I pass in a String object and can set that on the servlet. Right now, I'm getting the WebApplicationContext from the servlet context and using context.getBean() to get the bean.

Comment: Why the downvote? Also why the downvote to three other unrelated questions at the exact same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal Spring approach would be to **not** write your own servlets, but rather use the Spring WebApplicationCOntext together with a DispatcherServlet. I.e., your servlet would be replaced by a spring bean, configured to handle certain requests and injected with the JNDI object.

Comment: You're right, that would be better. My quick fix solution for the short term is to just get the WebApplicationContext and get a bean from it but I know that's not ideal.